# Android Facebook post error xmlPaseEntityRef: no name

Tags: android, facebook

I've been using facebook sdk for some time. When i first started using it was working fine. But since facebook changed the edit app page I've been getting an error every time i want to post something to my wall. My app, post information about a venue on the users wall.

Everytime i try to post something on the wall I first get a webview with the following Error:

> This page contains the following errors:  error on line 8 at column
>   35: xmlParseEntityRef: no name Repasrse document as HTML
>
> Below is rendering of the page up to the first error.
>
> CavalryLogger=false;window._script_path = "/wap/4oh4.php"
>   window._EagleEyeSeed ="Prm5"; Post to wall

When i press **Repast document as HTML**  it shows the post contents. The weird thing is when i do this in the emulator it works perfectly. I've added the debug hash key and private hash key. I've tried with different hash key as well, but can't seem to get around this problem.

Can anyone please help me?

Thank you

PS: This was peformd on a Samsung Galaxy Ace GT-S5830

Answer (score 1):

Updating the "Facebook" app on device solved this problem for me!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is you or a problem with your code.

This started today in the iOS app I am developing, and I'm seeing other reports of it on forums around the net.